# How to set the width of InputField in tables with dynamical content?

Tags: dynamic, inputfield

I have written the following code to generate the table that is shown below.

```
(* Titles and colors *)
TableFormatting[headers_,data_] := 
 DynamicModule[{rows=Range@Length@data,cols=Flatten@{"",headers}}, 
  Grid[Prepend[Transpose@Prepend[Transpose@data,rows],cols], 
   Frame->All, FrameStyle->GrayLevel[.9],Alignment->{Center,Center}, 
   Background->{{GrayLevel[0.8],None},{GrayLevel[0.8],None}}, Spacings->{2,Automatic}]]

(* InputFields and buttons to add/remove rows *)
table[titles_, initData_] := 
 Manipulate[TableFormatting[titles,Array[
  InputField[Dynamic[mat[[#1,#2]]],FieldSize->{{2.5,\[Infinity]},{1,\[Infinity]}}]&,Dimensions[mat]]], 
  {{mat, initData}, ControlType->None}, 
  ButtonBar[{" + ":>AppendTo[mat,Null&/@Range[Length[titles]]]," - ":>If[Dimensions[mat][[1]]>1,mat=Delete[mat,-1]]}],ControlPlacement->Right]

(* Example *)
table[{"Title1","Title2","Title3","Title4"},{{a,b,c,d},{1,2,3,4},{x,y,z,w}}]
```

[image]

However, I would like to improve it to auto-adjust the width of the InputFields so that all the cells in a column get resized to the width of the longest input in that column. e.g. In this picture, the width of the "xxxxxxxxx" cell should define the width of all the fields in that column.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[fieldSize, table2]
fieldSize[m_ : 2.5, h_ : 1] := 
  {{Max[{Map[StringLength @* ToString, #, {-1}] CurrentValue[
    "ControlsFontSize"]/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"], m}], ∞}, {h, ∞}} &

table2[titles_, initData_] := 
  Manipulate[TableFormatting[titles, 
    Array[
       InputField[Dynamic[mat[[#1, #2]]], 
         FieldSize -> fieldSize[] @ mat[[All, #2]]] &, 
       Dimensions[mat]]],
    {{mat, initData}, ControlType -> None}, 
    ButtonBar[{" + " :> AppendTo[mat, Null & /@ Range[Length[titles]]], 
      " - " :> If[Dimensions[mat][[1]] > 1, mat = Delete[mat, -1]]}], 
    ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

***Examples:***

```
table2[{"Title1", "Title2", "Title3", "Title4"},
  {{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {x, y, z, w}}]
```

[image]

Edit to replace `2` with `222222` and `z` with `zzzzzzzzzzzz`:

[image]

Add another row:

[image]

Delete the last 2 rows:

[image]

Comment: @JuanC97, please try the updated version.

Comment: It works smoothly @kglr, thanks a lot. Also, StringLength works exponentially better than Rasterize. That was a nice idea.

Comment: I included a factor of 0.6 here: (0.6)CurrentValue["ControlsFontSize"]/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]. It seems to fit a little bit better the contents of the boxes after clicking out of the table. Do you experience the same behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

```
InputField[x, FieldSize -> n]
```

And compute the FieldSize based on your inputs.

Comment: Following your comment and taking into account that the widths of the inputs may change, I've computed the max width per column using https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1862449 (up to a factor of 1/3 or so, to convert from pixels to ems). However, FieldSize seems to fail to auto-adjust the widths of the columns based on the user's input because of the way Dynamic[] is called in my previous code (note that it'd only lets us modify the width of the cell where the user is writing).